# Success Callback not called when $http post is in method scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zend-framework, angularjs-scope

I am trying to achieve a login functionality using `Angular JS` on front-end and `PHP  + Zend` on the back-end. Below is the code snippet of the angular js controller. This doesn't redirect the user to the appropriate page and while debugging, the control doesn't enter the `success` part but enters the `error` part `with data being NULL`. However **if I put the `$http` part outside the function, atleast the control enters the success part** with data being that of the next page to be redirected.

What could i be missing and what is the correct way to achieve the redirection?

In the below code the control doesn't enter the success section.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.authenticatelogin = function () {
        $http({
            url: "/admin/auth/authenticatelogin",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: $.param({login: $scope.login, password: $scope.password, rememberMe: $scope.remember})
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.location.href= "index/index";
                $scope.data = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
            });
        };
    });
```

In the below code the control enters the success section.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            url: "/admin/auth/authenticatelogin",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: $.param({login: 'abc@abc.com', password: 'xyzxyz', rememberMe: ''})
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $window.location.href= "index/index";
                $scope.data = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
        });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that invokes your authenticatelogin method. Also, are you using the zend dispatching/routing to handle navigation in your application?

Comment: What do you mean by "put the $http part outside the function"?

Comment: I have modified the question, please check the same. Yes the backend is using the zend dispatching/routing to handle the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather go for success/error callbacks to be part of the `then` method.
From angular documentation for version 1.4.5:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Try this one, although if you say that your code works outside the closure, it might not be the solution you are looking for:

```
$http({
    url: "/admin/auth/authenticatelogin",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $.param({login: $scope.login, password: $scope.password, rememberMe: $scope.remember})
}).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $window.location.href= "index/index";
    $scope.data = data;
}, function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```