# Angular 1.6.4 $http post callback not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, callback, request

I'm writing this Angular (1.6.4) service:

```
service.create = function(element, data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -- Post element
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/' + element.toLowerCase(),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: data,
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj) {
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            }
            return str.join('&');
        }
    }).then(function infoCallback(response) {
        console.log('yeah!');
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.error("[ FAILED ] >> " + response);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Data are posted well. But I don't know why, callbacks are not called.
It works well with get method.

I tried this unsuccessfully: [Success Callback not called when $http post is in method scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044505/success-callback-not-called-when-http-post-is-in-method-scope)

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: why did you give a name for the callback? you are not ging to use it any other place. try removing it.

Comment: Yes I tried this, but I have the same result. But yes, it useless. :)

Comment: Try use a network monitoring tool like Fiddler and verify that the request was made.

Comment: It was made, I have new line on my database.

Comment: I tried with Fiddler, the request works well.